# plotting column greater than 10

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a column greater than 10, but I get an error when I use {}.. like in regular bash. How do I tell gnuplot to do this?

```
plot '../data.txt' using (${11}:$2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give these two possibilities a try:

1. `plot '../data.txt' using 11:2`
2. `plot '../data.txt' using ($11):($2)`